# Can I affect the particle frequency of objects in a collection?

Tags: particles, hair, collections

[image]

So I have a scene that I am working on below. Currently I have only one type of tree simulated across the entire surface, but I want 3 different types instead. However I do not want an equal mix of these 3 trees, instead I want 80% of the first type of tree, 15% of the second, and 5% of the third.

Is there a way to put 3 trees in a collection and have the particle system affect the frequency of the objects inside it in this way?

- For extra points let me know if there are settings to help prevent these trees intersecting to heavily ( I will be going in close on my animation )

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://youtu.be/aZ5ungDgFNc?t=1055 This ought to help you deal with the tree mixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the particle settings select the Use Count for your collection. Then change the count for each item in the collection.  See the settings near the yellow arrow in the image above.

Comment: WOW!!! .... I love Blender so much ... just so so so much 

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: is it awful for me to ask you what you think about the extra credit question ... :o

Comment: Its not awful.  Its tempting for you to ask two related concept question in one BSE question.  Why not ask it separately? Its a gradient area sometimes.

Comment: GAHHHH, ... I actually DID ask it as two separate questions ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167449/how-to-prevent-the-intersection-of-mesh-particles

man oh man ... I can't help myself .... but seriously ... this is a game changer ... THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: That being said ... I thought there was this physics technique where different spheres were allowed to settle in place thus producing spacing. I would need to write something new to investigate

Comment: interesting ....

Comment: Ok, let me ask you one last question atomic ... you have showed me how to change the frequency ... but do you know of a way to then assign a texture map to that somehow and cluster these frequencies together ?

so when rare trees do show up they are surrounded by some of their kin...

Comment: Please place a new question.