# How to prevent the intersection of mesh particles

Tags: particles, collections

So I know this has been asked before, but the most recent article I could find was over a year ago so I am curious if this has been fixed.

I created the scene below by simply weight painting a subdivided plane and applying a collection of 3 objects as hair particles.

Can anyone recreate this scene WITHOUT any of these objects intersecting one another or is this still not possible to do in Blender?

[image]

Comment: As perhaps a partial solution.  You can create more faces and limit the emission of particles to one per face in the Particle emissions panel. This may create too much space for you in an artistic sense.  A triangle based mesh would somewhat limit non random pattern recognition.

Comment: I thought there was this physics technique where different spheres were allowed to settle in place thus producing spacing. I would need to write something new to investigate .. perhaps I am being lazy.

Comment: well still... I appreciate the effort!!!

Comment: Is it true you want to elimanate two tree trunks in the same place and are less concerned with branches intersecting?

Comment: I wonder if there are existing seamless images or data that address your issues.  I was trying a few web searches.  Other stack sites have similar questions.

Comment: Yes I want to avoid intersecting trunks and branches as I will be animating this shot and my camera will be going low through the valley ... so I don't want harsh looking overlaps. 

I certainly tried to search the topic out ..

Comment: There is the hexagonal grid.  Voronoi texture in Blender.  Penrose tiling.  There are probably other non Blender tools that generate those vertices and other useful data.  I just do not use them so its a long search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Perhaps part of a solution.  On the far right a single mesh has many triangles.  In the middle the mesh has some randomness introduced by user actions.  On the left is a render of particle system with minimal overlap and some randomness.

Of course my views are focused on a top down view for explanation purposes.  Your views will have artistic intention.

A Bit quick and dirty because there are not scripts or externals tools.  Some user action is required.

The far left image of triangles can be created by multiple means.  One method is to place 4 triangles in a mesh, add two array modifiers, then apply the array modifiers.  The triangle faces were for legibility.

In the middle part of the image.  Edit Mode, Face Mode. [Select Random] of faces by 10%. Or you can select faces manually. Copy and Paste faces or not. Toss a coin, Delete the faces .. or not. Then a proportional edit with [individual centers] and [Proportional Edit Falloff] Random or not. Adjust influence sphere. Repeat as necessary. Try many quick experiments and maybe the GPU will burn out. The distortion of the triangles was not a goal.  Proportional edit minimizes some work since it can operate on large portions of the mesh.  Be careful or mistake will occur with crowding.

On the right is the particle system.  Random <= False, Emit from faces, Particle/Faces <= 1, No Physics. No Gravity influence. Emission frame interval [1,1].  The idea was the Blender User Can see the locations.  If the terrain is flat enough a shrink wrap can be performed.

Perhaps a script would be easier.